# parameterMysteryReturn

Tags: java

in the following code:

```
public class MysteryReturn {
    //Given the following program:

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x = 1;
            int y = 2;
            int z = 3;

            z = mystery(x, z, y);                           // Statement 1
            System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);     // Statement 2
            x = mystery(z, z, x);                         // Statement 3
            System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);   // Statement 4
            y = mystery(y, y, z);                        // Statement 5
            System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);   // Statement 6

        }


        public static int mystery( int z, int x, int y) {
            z--;
            x = 2 * y + z;
            y = x - 1;
            System.out.println(y + " "+ z);
            return x;
        }
    }
```

I get the following results:

> Statement 1: 3 0
>
> Statement 2 :      1 2 4
>
> Statement 3 :      4 3
>
> Statement 4  :     5 2 4
>
> Statement 5  :     8 1
>
> Statement 6: 5 9 4

Statement 1 is perfectly clear to me, though don't get where does the 4 in Statement 2 come from ?

Comment: Good. Statement 1 returned 4. You print that 4 in statement 2 (as `z`). But since you understand statement 1, you must also then understand statement 2.

Comment: You shoot yourself into the foot by your really bad naming. Providing `x` as `z` is really confusing.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that's a Java riddle and therefore intended.

Comment: thank you, i get that statement 1 returned the 4, though why is it printed as z in statement 2 ? The code is not by me, im starting out and tryng to understand it.  its a java riddle as said by @Qbrute

Comment: Because you assigned the value of `mystery(x, z, y)`, which happens to be `4`, to `z`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what's going on step by step.

1. statement:

   ```
   public static int mystery( int z, int x, int y) {
                       // z=1, x=3, y=2
       z--;            // z=0
       x = 2 * y + z;  // x=4
       y = x - 1;      // y=3
       System.out.println(y + " "+ z);  // print: 3 0
       return x;       // return 4
   }
   ```

Now z is 4.

2. statement:

   ```
   System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z); // print: 1 2 4
   ```
3. statement:

   ```
   public static int mystery( int z, int x, int y) {
                       // z=4, x=4, y=1
       z--;            // z=3
       x = 2 * y + z;  // x=2*1+3=5
       y = x - 1;      // y=5-1=4
       System.out.println(y + " "+ z);  // print: 4 3
       return x;       // return 5
   }
   ```

Now x is 5. And z was 4 and y is stil 2.

4. statement:

   ```
   System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);   // print: 5 2 4
   ```
5. statement:

   ```
   public static int mystery( int z, int x, int y) {
                       // z=2, x=2, y=4
       z--;            // z=1
       x = 2 * y + z;  // x=2*4+1=9
       y = x - 1;      // y=9-1=8
       System.out.println(y + " "+ z);  // print: 8 1
       return x;       // return 9
   }
   ```

Now y is 9. z was 4 and x was 5.

6. statement:

   ```
   System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);   // print: 5 9 4
   ```